# Is There Any Way? To Manipulate My Token Price?

Tags: solidity, binance-smart-chain, new-blockchain

**What If?**
Is There Any Way? I Create a Coin Recently and Then Provide liquidity of **1 BNB = 100K LKZ** [Coin Name] after that I buy my own coin from another wallet 2 BNB = 200K LKZ but Now I Sell My 5M LKZ From 3rd Wallet ( a wallet Used to Deploy Smart Contract ) May I Get Profit Or Not?
I Know This Is Stupid Idea But It's My Idea ✌️

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely not.

As you are the only one depositing liquidity, you are the only one backing up the token with an asset that has value for other people (BNB). When you sell your token for BNB, you are just converting your assets between the token and BNB. When you remove the liquidity at the end, you will have the same total value (assuming nobody else interacts with the pool of course).